# Installing Nvidia graphics driver ubuntu

Tags: nvidia

I separately downloaded the `*.run` file Nvidia driver and used the grub `nouveau.modeset=0` for installing Nvidia graphics driver in Ubuntu which finally led to blinking and non usable tty. If I don't install the Nvidia driver, I will not be able to use `cuda` for `tensorflow`. Please help for a step by step guide to install Nvidia driver without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to download the .run file any more. The Nvidia drivers are available in Ubuntu default repositories.

To install it, Execute the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
```

NOTE : you might want to un-install all the previously installed nvidia drivers before installing these. To do that ,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

Comment: Is there any need for the modeset or the xconfig command later on?

Comment: Disabling nouveau by `nouveau.modset=0` in grub and executing the above commands to install the drivers on a tty is a Good habit , _But not mandatory_ .  No, there is no need of any xconfig  commands .

Comment: Are all the Nvidia drivers propritory or open source ones are also available

Comment: NO, Only nvidia-352 and nvidia-361 are available. If you want to yous the latest drivers, you can add  a ppa by `sudo apt-add repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` before executing the above given commands. They provide all the drivers . (But 361 is the stable version. 367 is still under development (beta) )